# fix scroll bar issue in chat div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My Ajax code:

```
function ajax() {
    var id = document.getElementById("chat");
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {   
            var scrollpos1 = $('#chat').scrollTop;
            var scrollpos = parseInt(scrollpos1) + 450;
            var scrollheight = $('#chat').prop('scrollheight');
            id.innerHTML = req.responseText; 
            if (scrollpos < scrollheight) {

            }
            else {
                $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat').prop('scrollHeight'));
            }
        }
    }

    req.open('POST','msg.php',true);
    req.send();
}

setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
```

I used this code to position the scroll bar at the bottom of the chat div, but I can't move the scroll bar back up. So my problem is: How can I get it so that the user can move the scroll bar up, while ensuring that the scroll bar jumps to the bottom after a new message goes into the chat div?

My CSS code:

```
#chat{
    width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: By not using `.innerHTML=` as this replaces the HTML and so resets the scroll position.   Look at appending only new messages.

Comment: This isn't possible, because your `innerHTML` is updated **every second**, thus pulling the scrollbar down whenever you scroll up. Try polling the webserver and only add the lastest messages or better yet use [`WebSockets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: how i can do that

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make this work! See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/a5ng03hu/).

Since I've built a chatroom component before, I'll explain how this master level scrollbar trick works.

What you need to do is to is:

1. Build 2 divs. The first is for the chat message window. The second is for a fake scrollbar div.
2. Give both divs the same height. In fact, they have the exact same `box` CSS class applied to them.
3. Float the divs next to each other.
4. Then reduce the scrollbar's width.
5. Position the scrollbar next to the chat window, so it looks like it's part of it.
6. A `.bottomDock` property is appended to the scrollbar's jQuery object. It's a hidden/invisible property, but it's a useful flag/boolean.
7. As the Ajax call round-trips from the server, it pushes 1 row to the bottom of the chatMessages window. It also pushes 1 `<BR>` tag to the bottom of the scrollbar window. This allows the 2x scrollbar heights to remain the same. Then it runs the `runScroll()` method to make sure that the heights are identical. (After all, long chat messages may wrap & 1 `<BR>` tag won't be enough! It would require 2 `<BR><BR>` tags, which we aren't adding.)
8. As the user mouses over the scrollbar, the `.bottomDock` boolean is flipped from `true` to `false`. That allows the scrollbar to disengage from it's docked position & allows the user to scroll freely up or down.
9. When moused out of the scrollbar, then the `.bottomDock` boolean is flipped back from `false` to `true`. It re-engages the bottom dock. This demo code automatically snaps back to that bottom docked position & chat messages will reappear to auto-scroll up as they did when the page loaded.
10. The `chatBox` also runs the `runScroll()` method, when it's bottom docked. This ensures that the scrollbar appears to be docked after the message is posted to the `chatMessages` window. Otherwise, the scrollbar wants to move up 1 row & flip the down arrow from gray (disabled state) to black (enabled state).

See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/a5ng03hu/) for a working demo of this code.

This is how a chatroom is built, using a fake scrollbar which is synchronized with the `chatMessages` window.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="chatRoom">
    <div id="chatMessages" class="box"></div>
    <div id="scrollbar" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.chatRoom .box {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;  
}

.chatRoom #chatMessages {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.chatRoom #scrollbar {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 8px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var chatBox = $('#chat');
var scrollbar = $('#scrollbar');

scrollbar.bottomDock = true;

function ajax() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST','anyUrl.php', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var msg = xhr.responseText;
            msg = '<div>' + msg + '</div>';
            chatBox.append(msg);
            scrollbar.append('<BR>');
            if (scrollbar.bottomDock) {
                runScroll();
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}

function runScroll(event) {
    if (scrollbar.bottomDock) {
        // Stay docked to the bottom
        var scrollHeight = chatBox[0].scrollHeight;
        scrollbar[0].scrollTop = scrollHeight;
        chatBox[0].scrollTop = scrollHeight;
    } else {
        // Scroll Freely
        scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
        scrollDirection = (scrollTop > scrollbar.lastScrollTop) ? 'down' : 'up';
        chatBox[0].scrollTop = scrollbar[0].scrollTop;
        scrollbar.lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    }
}

chatBox.on('scroll', function(event) {
    if (scrollbar.bottomDock) {
        runScroll(event);
    }
});

scrollbar.on('scroll', function(event) {
    if (!scrollbar.bottomDock) {
        runScroll(event);
    }
});

scrollbar.on('mouseout', function () {
    scrollbar.bottomDock = true;
    runScroll();
});

scrollbar.on('mouseover', function () {
    scrollbar.bottomDock = false;
});

setInterval(function() {
    ajax();
}, 1000);
```

I'll use this in my next project! Enjoy!